# No Titlebar with PYSimpleGUI in Python

Tags: python, taskbar, titlebar, pysimplegui

I want to make a small program using PySimpleGUI but when I include "no_titlebar = True" the taskbar icon also disappears. Is there a way to stop that? Thank you.

Comment: IMO, there's no way for it at this moment.

Comment: If using a Custom Titlebar, you'll get an icon if you minimize the window, but when it's visible, you're correct that it doesn't make an entry in the taskbar.  For "Desktop Widgets" or background task kinds of programs, it's great. For normal windows, not so great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use pywin32.
Install pywin32 first,

```py
pip install pywin32
```

python3.10 + Windows11

```py
from win32gui import *
from win32con import *
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)


def taskbar(window):
    hWnd = GetParent(window.winfo_id())
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_APPWINDOW)
    window.wm_withdraw()
    window.after(1, lambda: window.wm_deiconify())


def move(window):
    ReleaseCapture()
    hWnd = GetParent(window.winfo_id())
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                SC_MOVE + HTCAPTION, 0)


root.after(100, lambda: taskbar(root))
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda evt: move(root))
root.mainloop()
```